# Trying to determine why calling setState() doesn't change React component

Tags: javascript, dom, reactjs

I have a parent/child component hierarchy, the parent is the TestResultChooser and the child is a TestResult, like so:

```
  var TestResultChooser = React.createFactory(React.createClass({

            displayName: 'test-result-chooser',

            statics: {
                customMethod: function (foo) {
                    return foo === 'bar';
                }
            },


            getInitialState: function getInitialState() {
                return {overallTestResults: null};
            },

            changeOverallTestResult: function changeOverallTestResult(value) {
                this.setState({overallTestResults: value});
            },

            render: function render() {

                var self = this;

                var tests = this.props.items.map(function (testPath) {

                    return React.createElement(TestResult, {
                        key: testPath,
                        testName: testPath,
                        name: testPath,
                        testResult: null
                    });

                });

                return React.createElement('div', null, React.createElement('h1', null, 'Test Results:'),
                    React.createElement('div', {id: 'tests'}, tests, React.createElement('p', {id: 'total'}, ' ',
                        React.createElement('b', null, 'Test Results:', this.state.overallTestResults))))

            }
        }));

        var TestResult = React.createFactory(React.createClass({

            displayName: 'test-result',

            getInitialState: function getInitialState() {
                return {};
            },

            componentDidMount: function(){

                var self = this;
                var testPath = this.props.testName;

                console.log('component did mount'); // this is indeed logged!

                $.get(testPath).done(function (msg) {
                    var myWorker = new Worker('/js/workers/one.js');
                    myWorker.postMessage(msg);
                    myWorker.onmessage = function (msg) {

                        console.log('make new state:',msg);

                        self.setState(msg.data);
                    };
                }).fail(function (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                });
            },

            clickHandler: function clickHandler() {

                console.log('clicked!');  // this is indeed logged!

                this.setState({testName: 'foo-bar'});  //this should now change what is displayed...

            },

            render: function render() {

                var self = this;

                return React.createElement('p', {
                        className: this.state.active ? 'active' : '',
                        onClick: this.clickHandler,
                    },
                    this.props.testName, '  ', React.createElement('b', null, 'Pass/fail')
                );
            }

        }));


    ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(TestResultChooser, {items: stf}), document.getElementById('react-app'));
```

So when I click each of the children, the click is registered, but the testName doesn't change, so why doesn't calling setState change the displayed values in my small app?

Comment: I am starting to suspect that when the state changes for a child we need to manually notify the parent component?

Comment: If you need your parent to update when child state changes, move the state up to your parent, passing a function down to your child that calls `setState`. If that's not clear enough I can post an answer with an example.

Comment: thanks, yeah I tried the inverse of what you just said - passing a function, which belongs to the parent, to the child, and the child can call that function, but that doesn't seem to work

Comment: if you could post a quick example of what you're saying that would help, thanks

Comment: What you said is what I thought I was saying! Did you move state up to your parent?

Comment: idk wth is going on frankly, this should work

Comment: maybe because you're using `this.props.testName` instead of `this.state.testName` ?

Comment: ah maybe, will try that right now

Comment: yep that was it! can you explain why that is the case? I should probably just look up the difference between this.props and this.state...

Comment: @Road good catch. @Alex Mills: the component that has state uses its own state through `this.state`. When you pass something to a child, the child uses that from `this.props` https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html#a-brief-interlude-props-vs-state

Comment: you're using `setState` which changes the current `state` of your component. `this.props` is used when the property is from the `parent`. I usually use jsx so it will look something like this `<Parent><Child testName="testName" /></Parent>` with that, you can access the `testName` of Child as a prop.

Comment: I'd be lying if I said I knew exactly what you both mean, but it will help me get on track thanks